# Adding common characters in two strings into a new string

Tags: c, string, character

I wrote a function in C that looks like this:

```
char *common(char *a, char *b){
    char *result = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(b); j++){
            if (a[i] == b[j]){
                printf("%c", a[i]);
            }
            }
        }
    return result;
    }
```

It should compare the two given strings and give a new string with the common characters of those strings back. For example, strings: **hello world** and **thank you** would give back a string **ho**.

For now it just prints the characters and the result is empty, because I have a problem with getting the characters in the **result** string. How can I do that in this case?

Plus the result string shouldn't include duplicate characters, but each letter only once. I have no idea how to do that as well, but that's not the main problem.

Comment: Take a character pointer or character array to keep common characters and before saving check existanse.

Comment: assign value in result instead of printing and check for duplicate before assignment

Comment: what about cases?? small letter and capital letters?? H and h are same or different for this?

Comment: It should be unique characters, so in the result there can be both H and h. I don't know how to assign the value in result, that's the thing. Plus I don't know how do I check for duplicates.

Comment: okay means h and H are different character for your case???

Comment: Yes, they are, because they are different in ASCII.

Comment: Okay , get answer in answer section I write the complete code, first part is I just added functionality in your code and in next part I modified code little bit for your better understanding . All the best

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you, Its a working code. I just made very small change in your program and added what required. Soon I will optimized this. But first go through below code to understand the concept.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int isCharExist(char *str, char c){
 int i=0;
 while(str[i] != NULL){
  if(str[i] == c){
    return 1;
  }
  i++;
 }
 return 0;
}
char *common(char *a, char *b){
    char *result = "";
    int index = 0,i,j;
       for (i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
    for ( j = 0; j < strlen(b); j++){
        if (a[i] == b[j]){
        if(!isCharExist(result, a[i])){
         result[index++] = a[i];
         result[index] = '\0';//last character of string is always NULL

        }
        }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void main(){
  char *result = "",*str1,*str2;
  //better to assign space before assignment
  str1 = "hello world";
  str2 = "thank you";
  //clrscr();
  result = common(str1,str2);
  printf("%s",result);

}
```

The below code is better than above one and with small changes, I am not removing this one for your better understanding.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isCharExist(char *result, char c);
char *common(char *a, char *b);

int isCharExist(char *result, char c){
//this function help you to find that current character
//is in your result or not
 int i=0;
 while(result[i] != NULL){
  if(result[i] == c){
    //if it find character in result string it return 1
    return 1;
  }
  i++;
 }
 return 0;//if not find then it return 0
}

char *common(char *a, char *b){
    char *result = "";
    int index = 0,i,j;

    //it is good to keep length in seprate variable before loop
    //in loop it calculate length each time
    int len1 =  strlen(a);
    int len2 =  strlen(b);
       for (i = 0; i < len1; i++){
    for ( j = 0; j < len2; j++){

    //check equality but not for blank
        if (a[i] == b[j] && a[i] != ' '){
        if(!isCharExist(result, a[i]))
        {
         result[index++] = a[i];
         result[index] = '\0';//last character of string is always NULL

        }
        }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void main(){
  char *result = "",*str1,*str2;
  //better to assign space before assignment
  str1 = "hello world";
  str2 = "thank you";
  //clrscr();
  result = common(str1,str2);
  printf("%s",result);

}
```

The above one is just some changes in your function, so just replace your function not complete code.

```
char *common(char *a, char *b){
    char *result = "";
    int index = 0,i,j,k, isDuplicate=0;

    //it is good to keep length in seprate variable before loop
    //in loop it calculate length each time
    int len1 =  strlen(a);
    int len2 =  strlen(b);
       for (i = 0; i < len1; i++){
    for ( j = 0; j < len2; j++){

    //check equality but not for blank
        if (a[i] == b[j] && a[i] != ' '){
        k = 0;
        while(result[k] != '\0'){
            if(a[i] == result[k]){
              isDuplicate = 1;
              break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(!isDuplicate)
        {
         result[index++] = a[i];
         result[index] = '\0';//last character of string is always NULL

        }
        isDuplicate = 0;
        }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this one is for your understanding, how to assign and all.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error: conflicting types for 'isExist'

Comment: declare before use where you declared "char *common(char *a, char *b)" or keep isExist function above "char *common(char *a, char *b)" function.

Comment: If you are still getting error please change function name.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, but even if I copy your better code whole and run it, I get compiler exit status 1 because of clrscr(). But when I delete that, the console just waits for a while when I run it and then ends without printing anything.

Comment: In detail it tells me: Exited, segmentation fault. Just as with code from ganjaam.

Comment: which compiler you are using?

Comment: Please try to just replace your function by the function I added in end, and if it make some issue then once comment the break statement. you your main function and other code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have an array of `char` to the store the common characters. Then you need to store them subsequent to the order in which they occur but also proof if the character already were assigned to the array. After the loop was completely going though you have to assign the `\0` null character at the following element to indicate the end of the string. Furthermore you have to pass to extra parameters a pointer to a `char` array in the caller where the string with the common characters is stored and another parameter with the size of that array as its size can´t be determined inside the function:

```
char *common(char *a, char *b, char *c, size_t len){

    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(b); j++){
            if (a[i] == b[j]){
                printf("%c", a[i]);

                for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {  
                   if(c[i] == a[i])
                   {
                      continue;
                   }
                }

                if(i < len)
                {
                   c[k] = a[i];
                }
                else if( i > len )
                {
                   return NULL;
                }

                k++
            }
        }
    }

    x[k] = '\0';    

    return c;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the static part. This is a typical example where you would expect the caller to provide the buffer and buffer length, and use that. Using static memory outside a function is bad practice.

Comment: @Cheatah So, I´ve finally changed the answer. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you whole code but can help you with another approach. Simple way would be to make new string variable (result for example) where you would save common characters as you did (you can make it dynamically or with size of longest string between 2 you have), than you go through every element in one string with loop, than check with strchr() function from string.h if character is in another string, if it's in another string check again is it in result, if it's not just concatenate it to result with strcat(). I tried to explain it as clearly as I could. Hope it helps :)